# using sql rowcount in limit query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My Table looks like this:

```
id | Value
-----------
1  | High
2  | Medium
3  | Low
4  | Low
```

My php query looks like this:

```
    $sqlquery   = "select id from db_name order by id desc limit 3";  
    $fetchres   =  mysql_query($sqlquery);
    if(mysql_num_rows($fetchres)>0){
    while($result =  mysql_fetch_array($fetchres))  
    {   
    if($result['history']=='High'){?>

           <div style="background:#FF0000; width:50px; height:50px; vertical-align:middle;float:left;margin:0 10px 0 0"> </div>&nbsp;
    <?php } else if($result['history']=='Medium') {?>  
            <div style="background:#FF0; width:50px; height:50px; vertical-align:middle;float:left;margin:0 10px 0 0"> </div>&nbsp;
    <?php } else if($result['history']=='Low') {?>  
            <div style="background:#090; width:50px; height:50px; vertical-align:middle;float:left;margin:0 10px 0 0"> </div> &nbsp;
```

But it displays the results wrong

block 1 should be at block 3 and vice versa, block 2 stays where it currently is.

making sql query "asc" does not help, it only shows first 3 results and i need this to keep history of last three.

So my question is can you use something like rowcount within the sql query limit, if not how to correct the code to display it correctly.

Comment: what you mean with block 1? that is going to give you Low(4), Low(3), Medium(2).

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly: The rows coming from your query is correct, however the ordering is not?

Comment: A perfect example of BAD question. Instead of describing your GOAL you're asking for some term you have no idea of.

Comment: @ Gianaps that is how it displays it but i need it M, L, L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your SQL query yuo are selecting only id column `select id from`

Then you are comparing string values with non-existing index `history` from your result.

Correct this first and see if this will produce your desired result.